# Нарисовать овал поверх Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Допустим, мы хотим нарисовать что-либо. Мы переопределяем `DrawView` и в нём уже что-то рисуем. Но важно, что в главном `OnCreate()` мы тогда указываем `setContentView(new DrawView(this))`вместо нужного`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`то есть конструируемся не из основной разметки *activity_main*, которая уложена в XML файл, а из рисунка `DrawView`.

Мой вопрос в том, что можно ли, сохраняя основную разметку `activity_main`, нарисовать какие-либо фигуры?

P.S. С ними будет небольшая анимация, поэтому их не укладывая в XML файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартным средством для рисования является `Canvas`, который обычно берется или из `Bitmap` или из `SurfaceView`. Для `SurfaceView`:

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

код примерно такой:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    surface.getHolder().addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Do some drawing when surface is ready
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED); //рисуем здесь
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }
    });
```

Можно взять в качестве полотна не `SurfaceView`, а `Bitmap`, тогда:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//дальше рисуем на Canvas белую линию по диагонали
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);
```

Comment: Бесконечно признателен Вам за ответ!
Однако, есть ли какая-то существенная разница в скорости между SurfaceView и Bitmap?